# UIView loses constrains when animated

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview, constraints

I'm trying to imitate the controller push transition but for views. But it loses constrains the moment I add the constrains of the new view even before the animation occurs. For a reproduction of issue scroll to the gif at the bottom.

Here's a snippet of the relevant prosperities: (the rest is merely a bunch of labels and buttons)

```
//MARK: Properities
var credential: AuthCredential!
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var userAuthenticated = false
let controllerTitle = "Update Email"
private var timer: Timer?


lazy var credentialVerificationView: UIView = {
    let centerView = UIView()
    centerView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
    centerView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    centerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "blankSlate")
    return centerView
}()

lazy var emailUpdateView: UIView = {
    let centerView = UIView()
    centerView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
    centerView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    centerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return centerView
}()
```

I'm using transform to move the current view from the middle of the screen to -view.frame.width and the second view from -view.frame.width to the middle of the screen. func is:

```
private func startAutoScrollCardsCollectionView() {
    
    /// This method start timer and fire it immediately
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [unowned self] _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.credentialVerificationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -view.frame.width, y: 0)
        self.emailUpdateView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -view.frame.width, y: 0)                  
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the ugly bit:

```
//MARK: authenticateUserAndConfigureView
/// the purpose of this func is merely sentimental; as long as its there it stops me from ever writing UI ever again
    func authenticateUserAndConfigureView()  {
    //        title = controllerTitle
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "blankSlate")
    emailTextField.textContentType = .username
    emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    emailTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    emailTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    emailTextField.spellCheckingType = .no
    
    print("userAuthenticated = \(userAuthenticated)")
    
    if userAuthenticated == true {
        
        loginToContinueLabel.text = "Update Email"
        infoLabel.text = currentEmailLabel1.text
        errorLabel.text?.removeAll()
        startAutoScrollCardsCollectionView()
        emailUpdateView.addSubview(loginToContinueLabel)
        loginToContinueLabel.anchor(top: emailUpdateView.topAnchor,
                                    left: nil, bottom: nil,
                                    right: nil,
                                    paddingTop: 200,
                                    paddingLeft: 0,
                                    paddingBottom: 0,
                                    paddingRight: 0,
                                    width: 300, height: 50)
        loginToContinueLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        emailUpdateView.addSubview(infoLabel)
        infoLabel.anchor(top: loginToContinueLabel.bottomAnchor,
                         left: emailUpdateView.leftAnchor,
                         bottom: nil,
                         right: emailUpdateView.rightAnchor,
                         paddingTop: 24,
                         paddingLeft: 32,
                         paddingBottom: 0,
                         paddingRight: 32,
                         width: 0, height: 50)
        infoLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        emailUpdateView.addSubview(emailContainerView)
        emailContainerView.anchor(top: infoLabel.bottomAnchor,
                                  left: emailUpdateView.leftAnchor,
                                  bottom: nil,
                                  right: emailUpdateView.rightAnchor,
                                  paddingTop: 15,
                                  paddingLeft: 32,
                                  paddingBottom: 0,
                                  paddingRight: 32,
                                  width: 0, height: 50)
        emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        emailUpdateView.addSubview(verifyLabel)
        verifyLabel.anchor(top: emailContainerView.bottomAnchor,
                           left: emailUpdateView.leftAnchor,
                           bottom: nil,
                           right: emailUpdateView.rightAnchor,
                           paddingTop: 2,
                           paddingLeft: 32,
                           paddingBottom: 0,
                           paddingRight: 32,
                           width: 0, height: 20)
        emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        emailUpdateView.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.anchor(top: verifyLabel.bottomAnchor,
                          left: nil,
                          bottom: nil,
                          right: nil,
                          paddingTop: 1,
                          paddingLeft: 0,
                          paddingBottom: 0,
                          paddingRight: 0,
                          width: 0, height: 0)
        errorLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        emailUpdateView.addSubview(updateEmailButton)
        updateEmailButton.anchor(top: errorLabel.bottomAnchor,
                                 left: emailUpdateView.leftAnchor,
                                 bottom: nil,
                                 right: emailUpdateView.rightAnchor,
                                 paddingTop: 16,
                                 paddingLeft: 32,
                                 paddingBottom: 0,
                                 paddingRight: 32,
                                 width: 0, height: 50)
        updateEmailButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailUpdateView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(emailUpdateView)
        emailUpdateView.anchor(top: nil,
                               left: view.leftAnchor,
                               bottom: nil,
                               right: view.rightAnchor,
                               paddingTop: 0,
                               paddingLeft: +view.frame.width,
                               paddingBottom: 0,
                               paddingRight: -view.frame.width,
                               width: view.frame.width,
                               height: 0)

    } else {
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(loginToContinueLabel)
        loginToContinueLabel.anchor(top: credentialVerificationView.topAnchor,
                                    left: nil, bottom: nil,
                                    right: nil,
                                    paddingTop: 200,
                                    paddingLeft: 0,
                                    paddingBottom: 0,
                                    paddingRight: 0,
                                    width: 300, height: 50)
        loginToContinueLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: credentialVerificationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(infoLabel)
        infoLabel.anchor(top: loginToContinueLabel.bottomAnchor,
                         left: credentialVerificationView.leftAnchor,
                         bottom: nil,
                         right: credentialVerificationView.rightAnchor,
                         paddingTop: 24,
                         paddingLeft: 32,
                         paddingBottom: 0,
                         paddingRight: 32,
                         width: 0, height: 50)
        infoLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: credentialVerificationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(passwordContainerView)
        passwordContainerView.anchor(top: infoLabel.bottomAnchor,
                                     left: credentialVerificationView.leftAnchor,
                                     bottom: nil,
                                     right: credentialVerificationView.rightAnchor,
                                     paddingTop: 16,
                                     paddingLeft: 32,
                                     paddingBottom: 0,
                                     paddingRight: 32,
                                     width: 0, height: 50)
        passwordContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: credentialVerificationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.anchor(top: passwordContainerView.bottomAnchor,
                           left: credentialVerificationView.leftAnchor,
                           bottom: nil, right:
                            credentialVerificationView.rightAnchor,
                           paddingTop: 24,
                           paddingLeft: 32,
                           paddingBottom: 0,
                           paddingRight: 32,
                           width: 0, height: 50)
        loginButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: credentialVerificationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(needHelpButton)
        needHelpButton.anchor(top: loginButton.bottomAnchor,
                              left: loginButton.leftAnchor,
                              bottom: nil,
                              right: nil,
                              paddingTop: 0,
                              paddingLeft: 0,
                              paddingBottom: 0,
                              paddingRight: 0,
                              width: 0, height: 0)
        
        credentialVerificationView.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.anchor(top: needHelpButton.bottomAnchor,
                          left: credentialVerificationView.leftAnchor,
                          bottom: nil,
                          right: credentialVerificationView.rightAnchor,
                          paddingTop: 15,
                          paddingLeft: 32,
                          paddingBottom: 0,
                          paddingRight: 32,
                          width: 0, height: 0)
        errorLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: credentialVerificationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.view.addSubview(credentialVerificationView)
        credentialVerificationView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor,
                          left: view.leftAnchor,
                          bottom: view.bottomAnchor,
                          right: view.rightAnchor,
                          paddingTop: 0,
                          paddingLeft: 0,
                          paddingBottom: 0,
                          paddingRight: 0,
                          width: 0, height: 0)
        credentialVerificationView.center = self.view.center
    }
}
```

}

[image: The issue]

Comment: If you are using autolayout constraints then you can't animate the frame. You need to animate the constraints.

Comment: self.constraint.constant = ... ?

Comment: thing is the issue occurs even if I don't use the animate function

Comment: Ok, but what I am saying is that if you are using autolayout you can't modify the frame directly because you will conflict with the autolayout process.